# Magnetostriction: Equation and value of the relative length change

Tags: magnetostatics

Magnetostriction is a property of materials that causes them to change their length along the applied magnetic field.

In the [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriktion#Magnetostriktive_Konstante) an equation for the relative length change of materials is given.

$\lambda_\| = \frac{\Delta l}{l_0}$

Below this, a table shows some materials with negative and positive values for lambda. How I have to read the delta lambda? Length, before field application, minus length after? Or in reverse order?

A note. Perhaps someone remembers such experiments. For the diamagnetic materials Fe, Co and Ni the value is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative means shorter.  For anisotropic materials (e.g. single crystals), $\lambda$ may be a tensor. This means the changes in size do not necessarily occur solely along the direction of the field (i.e. the shape may change).