# Levitation of a diamagnetic material and the distance change when the magnetic field strength changes

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity, magnetostatics

If you have a diamagnetic material levitating in a magnetic field, will it rise higher as the magnetic field becomes stronger? And, at what height relative to the state described above is the material when it is made to float below the magnetic pole?

If there is a specialist here who can tell you something about this, then please also see question [Magnetostriction: Equation and value of the relative length change](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/597406/magnetostriction-equation-and-value-of-the-relative-length-change). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force is proportional to the field gradient rather than the field.  Paramagnetic materials ($\mu$>1) move towards regions of higher field whereas diamagnetic materials ($\mu$<1) move away from regions of high field. [Earnshaw's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem) dictates that stable levitation cannot be achieved in most situations.  The advantage of diamagnetic materials such as [frogs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlJsVqc0ywM) is that stable levitation can be achieved. 
Superconductors operate differently and will position themselves to try to avoid any changes in the flux threading the superconductor (or changes in the circulating currents).  Increasing the field source will generally cause the superconductor to move further from the source - up or down.